Star Gold additional baggage allowance on connecting JetBlue flight from Air India
I have an Air India ticket from India to the USA via JFK on a single PNR. Air India operates the international leg, and JetBlue operates the domestic leg within the US. The baggage allowance is specified as 2 pieces. As a Star Gold member, Air India offers an additional piece of luggage. Does this extend to JetBlue since it is a connecting flight on the same PNR?

Is your connecting flight booked under an AI flight number?

No, it has a JetBlue flight number.

That's a borderline case and. It may be spelled out in the fare rules but your best bet is to call the airline and ask. Even better: try to get this in writing.
I'm guessing this will be fine when you check in with Air India. However, for your return flight you will have to check in with Jet Blue and potentially with a contract agent (at a non-hub airport). These contractors often have no clue how any of this works and having a written document could help and certainly speed up the process.
